# $emit functions inside promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a problem with event orders, I have one method for getting data and another to open modal with data from previous method, and it works fine, but modal is rendered before getting data, so I see previous result for a sec. I do understand that I need my methods to be called in promise, but fail to realize how to do this.

**App.vue**

```
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">Gallery</h1>
      <Cards
        :images="images"
        @addImage="updateImage($event)"
        @showModal="showPopup($event)"
      />
      <Card :image="image" v-if="modal" @closeImage="toggleImage($event)" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Cards from "./components/Cards.vue";
import Card from "./components/Card.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: { Cards, Card },

  data: () => ({
    images: {},
    image: {},
    modal: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    updateImage: function (updatedImage) {
      this.image = updatedImage;
    },
    showPopup: function (state) {
      this.modal = state;
    },
    toggleImage: function (state) {
      this.modal = state;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Cards.vue**

```
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      v-for="image in images"
      :key="image.id"
      class="d-flex"
      cols="4"
      @click="
        getImage(image.id);
        toggleWindow();
      "
    >
      <v-img :src="image.url" :id="image.id">
        <template v-slot:placeholder>
          <v-row class="fill-height ma-0" align="center" justify="center">
            <v-progress-circular
              indeterminate
              color="grey lighten-5"
            ></v-progress-circular>
          </v-row>
        </template>
      </v-img>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Cards",
  props: ["images"],
  methods: {
    getImage(imageId) {
      fetch(`https://boiling-refuge-66454.herokuapp.com/images/${imageId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            return res.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error(res.status);
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          this.$emit("addImage", data);
        });
    },
    toggleWindow() {
      let toggle = true;
      this.$emit("showModal", toggle);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `getImage()` is an async method. It should return an Promise that resolves itself after the last then(). The last `then` is the one containing `this.$emit("addImage", data);`.

In your `@click` you should then wait for `getImage()` to be resolved before calling `toggleWindow()`.

So something like `@click="async () => { await getImage(image.id); toggleWindow();}"`.